# How to pause/resume RabbitMQ listener

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I have written the below listener to a Rabbit header Queue `queue`:

```
@Override
public void onMessage(final Message message)
{
    try {
        if (reindexEventListener.serviceFlag){
            System.err.println("Reindex started, Listener is stopped:\t");
            throw listenerExecutionFailedException("Reindex started, Log Event Listener is stopped");
        }
        else{
            String messageQ = new String(message.getBody(),"UTF-8");
            LOGGER.debug("Message from the Services:\t"+messageQ.toString());
            System.err.println("Message from the Services:\t"+messageQ.toString());
        }
    } 
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        LOGGER.error("Exception occur while  publishing the message", e);
    }
}
```

The flag `reindexEventListener.serviceFlag` in fact is set whenever an another queue `queue1` receives some message and binded to a listener for eg: `flagListener`.
I am able to consume the message coming to `queue` and based on the status set by `queue1` i am thrashing the message. But here the problem is that `queue` listener consumes the messages and these are no longer present in the queue. I want the `queue` to hold all the messages until `queue1` sets the status to `false`? Thanks in advance.!!

Answer (score 0):

In spring you can stop and start a listener.